How are "suicide points" considered to be 生活感のある表現 here?
A says to B that despite B's wishes they cannot go back to a castle to ask someone more about their upcoming journey and the reason they are embarking on it. The reason is that their "suicide points" are already accumulated to the brim, and meeting that person would increase them:

A: うん　おにいちゃんの 自殺ポイントはもうギリギリまで貯まっている
ほとぼりが冷めるまでは 会わないほうがいい
B: 自殺ポイントって何だよ
和まねえよ そんな 生活感のある表現をされても

The translation calls 生活感のある表現 a "euphemism". From what I can tell, 生活感 has to do (figuratively) with a sort of desirable, perhaps "down to earth" feel in the sense of something naturally existing or appearing within the lives of everyday people. But it does seem rather vague looking at this 新明解 definition:

その△人（物）の持つ全体的な雰囲気の中に、気さくな庶民の日びの生活のにおい・感覚と、ごく自然な かげりとが
おのずから現われていて、好ましい感じ。 「━にあふれる女優」

I don't know if this means that "suicide points" is a phrase that normal people would naturally tend to use (and apparently that would be a good thing), or if it means that because A is kind of a supernatural being and B is more human-like, using a made on the spot phrase like that is supposed to resonate with B more because it is something a human might say. Neither of these explanations really work for me however because I cannot imagine how "suicide points" is something people (or humans) would naturally want to say and/or enjoy saying.

Not very sure from the given context, but perhaps "casual, folksy sounding" in this situation?

It's generally recommended to show context and not try to explain it or translate it, since that removes the chance that some piece of context was misinterpreted.

I looked up the line in the anime adaption(e4 11:30), and the visual shows a point card, making it explicit that the term "suicide points" references reward points you get at a store. This is a metaphor for his suicidal urge building up in the previous scene.
I think it's intended as a joke on her part, while reiterating that he can't go back to ask more questions. I've seen the show and I think it's typical of the way Nishio Ishin likes to play with words. It's supposed to be a little silly.
As for why he would want to die, at the beginning of the scene Yotsugi says: "簡単に言うと、その威光にあてられて、死にたくなってしまうっていうのかな。" referring to the supernatural influence of the character Araragi was talking to in the castle. Also, in that scene you hear his internal monologue turning towards wanting to die, as though against his will. It's a little surreal, but I think we're supposed to accept that's how it works in the setting.
I'm not a native speaker or close to that level, so I don't know if 生活感 is idiomatic in this context or if it's used figuratively, but it probably refers to how ordinary and 'daily-life'ish reward points are in contrast to suicide.
Edit: Show/novel is Zoku Owarimonogatari, for anyone interested.

+1 for good research.

It's hard to answer this without knowing the title (or at least the genre) of this work. Are these speakers residents of modern Japanese society who have been transported to an isekai?
自殺ポイント is certainly not a familiar phrase, but ポイントが貯まっている is a very common phrase in everyday Japanese life. Most people have many digital or paper point cards. So I guess 生活感がある refers generally to such point systems, not specifically to suicide points. This tsukkomi is probably pointing out that even though point systems are a familiar concept in daily life, using it to express the possibility of suicide won't lighten his mood.
